# Can I use German save games with a UK import game for the PS2?

Tags: ps2, final-fantasy-12

I've been playing the German translation of Final Fantasy 12 on a German PS2 for some time now, but the horrible translations have really made the story somewhat incomprehensible...

Now I wanted to try and buy a UK Import version and was wondering if I could continue my saves from where I left off?

I remember the PSP allowed me to start a German save and then just overwrite it with an English version, but I'm not sure about the PS2...

Comment: I think it's game dependent. In any case, it will only work on games from the same region.

Comment: the UK and Germany are in the same region to my knowledge, or am i wrong?

well. if no1 comes along who actually tried this, then i'll bite the bullet an try it myself :D thanks johnoboy!

Comment: They would both be PAL games, but they would probably be different versions of the games, so I cannot be sure if the save would be exactly the same. I went ahead and checked some online save resources and they only list saves for PAL versions of FFXII. I assume those saves were made on the UK version. Try playing those with your copy of the game (for example on an emulator or by copying the save to a physical card using a USB adapter). If they'd work, it'll probably also work the other way around.

Comment: "the horrible translations have really made the story somewhat incomprehensible" - I don't think having the game in English will make the story itself any less incomprehensible ;)